# Display the whole filled form after submitting the form

Tags: html, jquery

I am making a form using html. I want to display whole form filled after submitting the form.
Like after filling all the field when I click on submit then it will return filled form & not editable which user can save or print the form. Like what happen in google form after submitting it return a filled form.

```js
// making checkbox required & select only one checkbox from multiple checkbox
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check').click(function() {
    let name = $(this).attr("name")
    const textInput = $(this).closest('.row').find('input[type="text"]').first()
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').prop('required', false);
      textInput.prop('required', false);
    } else {
      $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').prop('required', true);
      textInput.prop('required', false);
    }
    $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false)
  });
});
$('#ofc_use').on("change", function() {
  if ($('#update').prop('checked')) {
    $('#ofc_use input[type="text"]').prop("required", true);
    $('#crnt_add input[type="checkbox"]').prop("required", false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-lg py-3">
  <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 bg-warning ps-3">
    <h3 class="d-inline"> 1. PERSONAL DETAILS</h3>
    <span class="align-text-bottom"> (Please refer to Instruction A at the end)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Name</h4>
      <p class="d-inline">* (same as ID proof)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="text" id="prefix" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="prefix" required></div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3"><input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="first name" required></div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="text" id="mname" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="middle name"></div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="last name" required></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Date of Birth*</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="date" class="form-control border-0" required></div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-1">
      <h4 class="d-inline">PAN*</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3"><input type="text" id="pan" class="form-control border-0" required></div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Form 60 furnished</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Gender*</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="gender" class="check form-check-input" required> Male</div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="gender" class="check form-check-input" required> Female</div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-5"><input type="checkbox" name="gender" class="check form-check-input" required> Transgender</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Marital Status*</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="marital" class="check form-check-input" required> Married</div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="marital" class="check form-check-input" required> Unmarried</div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-5"><input type="checkbox" name="marital" class="check form-check-input" required> Others</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Nationality*</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="nationality" class="check form-check-input" required> IN-Indian</div>
    <div class="border border-dark border-bottom-0 col-lg-7"><input type="checkbox" name="nationality" class="check form-check-input" required> Others(ISO 3166 Country Code)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3">
      <h4 class="d-inline">Residental Status*</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="resident" class="check form-check-input" required> Resident Individual</div>
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="resident" class="check form-check-input" required> Non Resident Indian</div>
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" name="resident" class="check form-check-input" required> Foreign National</div>
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3"><input type="checkbox" name="resident" class="check form-check-input" required> Person of Indian Origin</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: And what is your question? May be the showed form on google service is filled by code wich is running on server side.

Comment: the values of the inputs will remain until the form is refreshed or the page is loaded again. To prevent that, you can use localStorage or sessionStorage. Then to disable the editing you can use use `readonly`